# Is it haram to get to seek information for an exam from somebody who already took the exam?

Tags: halal-haram, education, cheating

Is it haram to get to seek information for an exam from somebody who already took the exam? For example, me and my friend both took the same math exam. however she took it before me. Is it islamically permissible for my friend to give me details on the exam so that I might get a better grade.

Comment: getting advice and information might be permissible if you know that the paper will not be same and you are not asking what has came in exam, instead you can ask for probable questions, and info related to paper? not inside the paper

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you will get the exact same questions? If so, surely this is a failure of the exam system, they should know that students will talk to each other about the exam if they schedule it this way.

Comment: I think this question has nothing to do with religion. It is related to common sense and your natural understanding of right and wrong. The purpose of exams is to test your competence. Why would you take help when the sole purpose is to evaluate your learning capabilities? I believe that Islam only guides on issues which a sane person could not resolve on his own. Other than that, use your intuition and common sense which are God given gifts.

Comment: Why should it be haram? Relevant [Is "X" halal (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.5560)

Comment: @mmm-anonymouse I’m a teacher. The purpose of an exam is obviously not to evaluate your learning capabilities, but to evaluate your actual knowledge.

Comment: @user354948, you're correct. I should have said it better.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is haram. It is considered haram to cheat since cheating can be seen as a kind of 'lie' and it would be lying to take the test to show what are supposed to be your own abilities, but are actually answers you got from someone else.

> Verily, those who forge lies they are Those who do not believe in Allah's Signs and Revelations and they are Indeed the liars. (Al-Nahl 105)

> ... Indeed Allah does not guide someone who is a liar and an ingrate.(39:3)

> [As stated by "Manual of Islamic Laws for Students" in response to the foregoing question, the grand jurists have unanimously and explicably considered cheating as impermissible.](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1411)